# incomplete type error , when using friend functions

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
class B;

class A;

class A
{
    int a;
    friend int B::f();
};


class B
{
    int b;
    class A x;
public:
    int f();
};

int B::f()
{
    // ...
}

main()
{
    class B b;
    b.f();
}
```

ERRORS:

```
a.cpp:9: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct B’

a.cpp:2: error: forward declaration of ‘struct B’
```

The issue cannot be solved by placing definition of B before A as
B has an object of type A.

For this example making B a friend class would do, but in 
my real code I have more member functions in B (so I need alternative solution).

Finally, can somebody give me links that explain what the compiler does when it comes
across a forward declaration, declaration, definition.

Comment: The problem is that the C++ compiler is a "one-pass" one, meaning that it won't try to keep something it is not able to understand now and try to solve it later, when it has more info (in this example, about class B). Why this is still like that nowadays, is beyond me. Anyway, as far as I understand, making B a friend class of A would work. Or do you mean that you have to give access to other member funtions outside B?

Comment: @Baltasarq: imagine the same piece of code compiled to something different depending on what comes *after*. Which compiled language has this "feature"?

Comment: @eudoxos: Java, for one. It's syntax requires a multipass compiler. And C++ for another (but only within a class). For example, `class Foo {public: set_item (int val) {item = val;} private: int item;};`

Comment: Undefined behaviour there too, main must have a return type of `int` and only int

Comment: @eudoxos: David Hammen suggested Java, which is a great example. I know in more depth C#, and in that case, a given module is compiled firstly only with the stubs for the members of classes, in order to be able to solve external references when circular dependencies are present, and finally once all checks are ok, all modules are compiled with all code.

Comment: @ Baltasarq - I do not want other member functions of B ( assume there are some ..) to have   access to private members of A, which would happen if i made A a friend class of B ).

Comment: @David Hammen, @Baltasarq: agreed. c++ cannot be really compared to Java in this respect, though, due to preprocessor `#include` rather than proper modules for separating components.

Answer (score 3):

Define`B` before `A`, and declare a pointer to `A` as member data of `B`:

```
class A; //forward declaration

class B
{
    int b;
    A  *px; //one change here - make it pointer to A
 public:
    int f();

};

class A
{    
    int a;
    friend int B::f();
};
```

Or, you could make the entire class `B` a friend of `A`, that way you don't have to make the member data *pointer to `A`*.

```
class B; //forward declaration

class A
{    
    int a;
    friend class B;
};

class B
{
    int b;
    A   x; //No change here 
 public:
    int f();

};
```

Answer (score 2):

You simply cannot do what you want to do as-is. To make that friend function declaration in class `A` the nature of class `B` needs to be known prior to the definition of class `A`. To make class `B` contain an instance of class `A` the nature of class `A` must be known prior to the definition of class `B`. Catch-22.

The former does not apply if you make class `B` a friend class of class `A`. The latter does not apply if you modify `B` to contain a pointer or reference to an instance of class `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Forward declare class A; define class B; define class A; define B::f.

```
#include <cstdio>
class A;


class B
{
int b;

public:
int f();
};

class A
{
int a;
friend int B::f();
};


int B::f()
{
}

main() 
{
class B b;
b.f();
}
```